# Using robots.txt to hide a specific parameter

Tags: html, search-engine, robots.txt

Good day.

So i want to hide a page on my site from search engines. My link looks like:
http://something.somethingelse.com/?asd=22151

To hide the page corresponding to "asd=22151", it's enought if i add the following line to robots.txt?

Disallow: /*?asd=22151

Comment: I;m not sure you need the `*` - but you should put the robot.txt in the top-level directory - which corresponds to the root of your web server `http://something.somethingelse.com/`

Comment: Also: See the last entry on this page: `http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html` for examples of how to disallow single pages ... note there's no `*`

Comment: Thank you  @GavinBrelstaff! :)